# how can remove part of figure caption from list of figure in latex?

Tags: captions

I have this caption of figure:
`\caption{these are my figure. (a):aaaaa. (b): bbbbbb.}` that appear in below of figure in text.
All part of this caption appear in list of figure. I want only appear this :
`these are my figure.` in list of figure. is there any way ?

Comment: `\caption[these are my figure]{these are my figure. (a):aaaaa. (b): bbbbbb}`

Comment: Before piling up some questions, it's better to give feedback to the users who answered other questions by you) (Yes, I am one of them, but not the only one) ;-)